# How to get status of portfolio saga item by story hours?

Tags: rally

Does anyone know an easy way to get a percent done by story hours related to 'Portfolioitem/Saga'? The existing portfolio items app in CA only shows percent done by story plan estimate and I'd like to get the task hours details as well.

I've written the following custom app to include the data but my table gets loaded before the data is returned. Please help!

```
Ext.define('Rally.app.PortfolioGrid', {
            extend: 'Rally.app.App',
            componentCls: 'app',

            launch: function() {
                console.log('Working');
                this._loadComboBox();
            },

            _loadComboBox : function() {
                this.searchComboBox = Ext.create('Rally.ui.combobox.ArtifactSearchComboBox', {
                    fieldLabel: 'Saga',
                    noEntryText: '',
                    emptyText: 'Enter saga ID or keyword...',
                    //grow: true,
                    //allowNoEntry: false,
                    storeConfig: {
                        autoLoad: true,
                        models: ['PortfolioItem/Saga']
                    },
                    listeners: {
                        select: function(combobox, records) {
                            this._loadData();
                        },
                        scope: this
                    }
                });
                this.add(this.searchComboBox);
            },

            _loadData: function () {
                var selectedID = this.searchComboBox.getRecord().get('FormattedID');
                console.log('Selected Saga', selectedID);
                var myFilters = [
                    {
                        property: 'FormattedID',
                        operation: '=',
                        value: selectedID
                    },
                ];
                if (this.myStore) {
                    console.log('store exists');
                    this.myStore.setFilter(myFilters);
                    this.myStore.load();
                  // create store
                } else {    
                    this.myStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
                        model: 'PortfolioItem/Saga',
                        autoLoad: true,
                        fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'Children', 'Release', 'State', 'PercentDoneByStoryPlanEstimate', 'PercentDoneByStoryCount', 'Project', 'Owner'],
                        filters: myFilters,
                        listeners: {
                            load: this._onDataLoaded,
                            scope: this
                        }
                    });
                }           
            }, 

            _onDataLoaded: function(store, data){
                var features = [];
                var pendingstories = data.length;
                Ext.Array.each(data, function(feature) {
                            var f  = {
                                FormattedID: feature.get('FormattedID'),
                                Name: feature.get('Name'),
                                _ref: feature.get("_ref"),
                                State: (feature.get('State') && feature.get('State').Name) || ' ',
                                Project: (feature.get('Project') && feature.get('Project').Name) || ' ',
                                Owner: (feature.get('Owner') && feature.get('Owner')._refObjectName) || 'No Owner',
                                PercentDoneByStoryPlanEstimate: Math.floor(feature.get('PercentDoneByStoryPlanEstimate') * 100) + '%',
                                PercentDoneByStoryCount: Math.floor(feature.get('PercentDoneByStoryCount') * 100) + '%',
                                Children: [],
                                totalPlannedHours: 0,
                                totalHoursRemaining: 0,
                                totalHoursCompleted: 0,
                                Percentage: 0                                   
                            };

                            var sagaFeatures = feature.getCollection('Children');
                            sagaFeatures.load({
                                fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Parent', 'UserStories', 'DirectChildrenCount'],
                                callback: function(records, operation, success){
                                    Ext.Array.each(records, function(child){ 
                                            var s = {
                                                FormattedID: child.get('FormattedID'),
                                            };  

                                            if (child.get('DirectChildrenCount') > 0) {
                                                child.getCollection('UserStories').load({
                                                fetch: ['FormattedID', 'TaskEstimateTotal', 'TaskRemainingTotal'],
                                                callback: function(records, operation, success) {
                                                    Ext.Array.each(records, function(us) {
                                                        f.totalPlannedHours += us.get('TaskEstimateTotal');
                                                        f.totalHoursRemaining += us.get('TaskRemainingTotal');
                                                        f.totalHoursCompleted = f.totalPlannedHours - f.totalHoursRemaining

                                                        console.log("Total Hours Completed", f.totalHoursRemaining)

                                                        f.Percentage = Math.floor((f.totalHoursCompleted / f.totalPlannedHours) * 100) + '%'; 

                                                    }, this);


                                                }, scope: this});
                                            }                                               
                                            f.Children.push(s);

                                    }, this);

                                },
                                scope: this
                            });

                            features.push(f);

                            --pendingstories;
                            if (pendingstories === 0) {
                                this._createGrid(features);
                            } 

                }, this);

                this._createGrid(features);
            },

            _createGrid: function(features) {
                var myCustomStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
                    data: features
                    //pageSize: 100,
                });
                if (!this.grid) {
                    this.grid = this.add({
                    xtype: 'rallygrid',
                    flex: 1,
                    store: myCustomStore,
                    columnCfgs: [
                        {
                           text: 'Formatted ID', dataIndex: 'FormattedID', xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                            tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.FormattedIDTemplate')
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'Name'
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'State', dataIndex: 'State'
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Saga Features', dataIndex: 'Children', 
                            renderer: function(value) {
                                var html = [];
                                Ext.Array.each(value, function(child){
                                    html.push('<a href="' + Rally.nav.Manager.getDetailUrl(child) + '">' + child.FormattedID + '</a>')
                                });
                                return html.join(', ');
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Percent Done By Story Plan Estimate', dataIndex: 'PercentDoneByStoryPlanEstimate'
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Percent Done By Story Count', dataIndex: 'PercentDoneByStoryCount'
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Total Planned Hours', dataIndex: 'totalPlannedHours'
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Total Completed Hours', dataIndex: 'totalHoursCompleted'
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Percent Done by Story Hours', dataIndex: 'Percentage'
                        }, 
                        {
                            text: 'Project', dataIndex: 'Project'
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Owner', dataIndex: 'Owner'
                        }
                    ]

                    });
                }
                else {
                    this.grid.reconfigure(myCustomStore);
                }
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you load the data from the bottom up instead and save yourself all the many nested loops and store loads?

I think you should be able to just create a store of stories beneath the selected saga...

```
this.myStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
    model: 'UserStory',
    autoLoad: true,
    limit: Infinity,
    pageSize: 2000,
    fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'TaskEstimateTotal', 'TaskRemainingTotal', 'Feature', 'Parent', 'Children'],
    filters: [{ property: 'Feature.Parent', operator: '=', value: this.searchComboBox.getRecord().get('_ref')}],
    listeners: {
        load: this._onDataLoaded,
        scope: this
    }
});
```

And then just crunch your data into the appropriate data structure, bucketing them by Feature.  Something like this?

```
_onDataLoaded: function(store) {
    var sagas = {};
    var stories = store.getRange();
    _.each(stories, function(story) {
        var feature = store.get('Feature'),
            saga = feature.Parent;

        if (!sagas[saga._ref]) {
            sagas[saga._ref] = Ext.clone(saga);
        }
        var featureChildren = sagas[saga._ref].Children.values = sagas[saga._ref].Children.values || {};
        if (!featureChildren[feature._ref]) {
            featureChildren[feature._ref] = Ext.clone(feature);
        }

        var storyChildren = featureChildren[feature._ref].UserStories.values = featureChildren[feature._ref].UserStories.values || {};
        if (!storyChildren[story._ref]) {
            storyChildren[story._ref] = Ext.clone(story);
        }
    });

    //now you have an object of sagas, just needs to be an array for your custom store data
    var customStoreData = _.values(sagas);
    this._createGrid(customStoreData);
}
```

Something like that should get you close.  You'll need to move around your code a little bit where you're calculating your rollup totals, and your renderer for the Children column will be a tiny bit different- just loop over `_.values(value.values)` instead.

Comment: Kyle, Thanks for your response. I'll try the suggested approach and let you know if that worked.

Comment: Hi Kyle, I'm getting the following error when I create a store of stories beneath a saga 'msg: "Could not find registered factory for type:  UserStories", sourceMethod: "getModel", sourceClass: "Rally.data.ModelFactory", message: "Could not find registered factory for type:  UserStories"'.

Comment: The type shoudl be HierarchicalRequirement, or UserStory (singular).  I was also thinking you'll probably want to add a filter for DirectChildrenCount = 0 if you use epic stories so you only get leaf stories- wouldn't want to double count task rollups if epic stories were included...

Comment: Thank you! It works now but I'm having a hard time creating a grid by the saga. Do you have an example code that you can share with me?

Comment: I just added some code that hopefully should help you bucket stories and features beneath their sagas.